# Diophantine problem in n log n

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $x_n = n \log n$ for $n \geq 1$. What is a good upper bound for the number of solutions $(n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4) \in \{1, \dots, N\}^4$ of
$$
|x_{n_1} - x_{n_2} + x_{n_3} - x_{n_4} | < \gamma,
$$
say for $\gamma$ in the range $[1/N,1]$? The dependence in $N$ clearly should be around $N^3$, but is it true that the dependence in $\gamma$ is roughly linear? More specifially, is it true that the number of solutions is $\ll \gamma N^{3 + \varepsilon}$.